# Rails Ruby slect_tag :include_blank not selected as default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
 <%= select_tag(:event_type, options_from_collection_for_select(@event_types, 'id', 'name', 1),  { :include_blank => true } ) %>
```

This will generate all option needed but the blank select is not selected by default. Why

Answer (score 1):

Fourth argument of `options_from_collection_for_select` method is selected value. "1" in your case. Use `options_from_collection_for_select(@event_types, 'id', 'name')`

[options_from_collection_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)